# Switching between two strings after button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift

So I am working on a BlackJack game for iOS using Swift. I have two buttons, HIT and STAY. Here is where my problem lies: When I press the originally, it is player 1's turn. But after clicking the HIT button, I want the turn label to oscillate between player 2 and player 1. So after player 1 clicks HIT button, I want the turn label to read player 2 and then player 1. Here is what I got so far:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var deck = PlayingCardDeck()

    @IBOutlet weak var cardLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var playerTurn: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var scorePlayerOne: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var scorePlayerTwo: UILabel!
    
    
    @IBAction func btnHit(_ sender: Any) {
        cardLabel.text = String(describing: deck.drawCard()!)
        playerTurn.text = String(describing: "Player 2")

    }
    
    @IBAction func btnStay(_ sender: Any) {
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        deck.shuffle()
    }

}
```

With the method I have, it mimics what I want to happen (switches to player 2)

Answer (score 0):

You need a variable to track which player is currently playing and then change the label based on those variable value.

```
var isFirstPlayerTurn: Bool = true

@IBAction func btnHit(_ sender: Any) {
    cardLabel.text = String(describing: deck.drawCard()!)
    isFirstPlayerTurn = !isFirstPlayerTurn
    playerTurn.text = isFirstPlayerTurn ? "Player 1" : "Player 2"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two labels, one for each player. Then hide player 2's label and flip it while hidden in viewDidLoad(). Once the turn changes, flip both labels while simultaneously showing and hiding the labels based who's turn it is.

To flip the label, use CGAffineTransform. Use the labels' alpha property to show and hide the labels.

```
func changeTurn(_ player: Int) {   

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        playerTurn1.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -playerTurn1.transform.a, y: playerTurn1.transform.d)
        playerTurn2.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -playerTurn2.transform.a, y: playerTurn2.transform.d)
        playerTurn1.alpha = player == 1 ? 1 : 0
        playerTurn2.alpha = player == 2 ? 1 : 0
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
@IBOutlet weak var playerTurn1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var playerTurn2: UILabel!

private var turn = 1

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    deck.shuffle()

    playerTurn2.alpha = 0
    playerTurn2.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -playerTurn2.transform.a, y: playerTurn2.transform.d)
}

@IBAction func btnHit(_ sender: Any) {
    cardLabel.text = String(describing: deck.drawCard()!)
     
    turn = turn == 1 ? 2 : 1
     
    changeTurn(turn)
}
```

Make sure both labels are the same frames.